# mapdb how to persist cross restart

Tags: database, scala, mapdb

I use `mapdb` as following

```
val mycache = DBMaker.newFileDB(new File(("/data/tmp/cache.db")))
    .transactionDisable()
    .make().getHashSet("")
```

then when i do

```
mycache.put(k1, v1)
assertTrue(mycache.get(k1), v1) // all is fine
```

however if i restart my server i do see i have cache.db on disk however it will have an empty map when reading

so

```
mycache.get(k1) // is null after restart
```

how can i have it reread my map after restart from file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to close database before JVM shutdown. Easiest is to add `.closeOnJVMShutdown()` option